# array : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=message_receiver', 'root', '',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$itms = [];
$i = 0;
for ($i ; $i < count($json); $i++) {
  $itms[] = '(
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['server.timestamp'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.longitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.latitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['timestamp'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.altitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.direction'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.speed'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . intval($json["result"][$i]['position.satellites'] ?? 0) . '
  )';
}
try
{
$requete = $bdd->prepare("
 UPDATE
 php_message_listener
 SET 
 server.timestamp =?,
 position.longitude =?,
 position.latitude =?,
 timestamp =?,
 position.altitude =?,
 position.direction =?,
 position.speed =?,
 position.satellites =?,
 WHERE ident = '$ident_same_update'
 ");
 $requete->execute(array(json_encode($itms)));
}catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I see eight `?` (placeholders) and one string element passed to `execute()`.  Where is your confusion? Did you read the manual?  It is Unclear (to me) why this unexplained code dump is written the way that it is.

Comment: hello , no It's not a single item but that is an array which contains 8 item

Comment: `array(json_encode($itms))` is an array with a lone element containing a json_encoded string.

Comment: How do I pass it because when I print the (gettype($itms)) Get "Array" result

Comment: Simply replace `array(json_encode($itms))` with `$itms`. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php . Just noticed: `$itms` needs to be an array of values. You defined it as an array having a single concatenated string. This will not work.

Comment: <strong>ArrayErreur : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens</strong> the same probleme

Comment: `$requete->execute($itms);` not work with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code. Firstly, replace

```
$itms = [];
$i = 0;
for ($i ; $i < count($json); $i++) {
  $itms[] = '(
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['server.timestamp'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.longitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.latitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['timestamp'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.altitude'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.direction'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . floatval($json["result"][$i]['position.speed'] ?? 0) . ',
    ' . intval($json["result"][$i]['position.satellites'] ?? 0) . '
  )';
}
```

with

```
$i=0;$jri=$json["result"][$i];
$itms = [
  $jri['server.timestamp'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.longitude'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.latitude'] ?? 0,
  $jri['timestamp'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.altitude'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.direction'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.speed'] ?? 0,
  $jri['position.satellites'] ?? 0
]
```

And secondly, further down, replace

```
$requete->execute(array(json_encode($itms)));
```

with

```
$requete->execute($itms);
```

This should supply the required array with 8 elements to the `PDO::execute()` method. I haven't tested it but I expect it to work.

From your question it is not clear how many elements there are in the array `$json["result"]`. With the above snippet (`$i=0`) only the first element will be considered. You might have to use a loop if you want to do the same action with all elements of `$json["result"]`. But for this case you should also make `ident` in your MySQL table `php_message_listener` parametric, i. e. bind a suitable PHP variable with the relevant id to it using another `?` in your `bdd->prepare()` statement. The current PHP variable `$ident_same_update` seems to contain only *one* value.

Comment: thank you so much carsten , i appreciate that , just i got this error when i do what u tell me `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in`

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Basically you need to make sure that `$itm` contains 8 values, the first and fourth need to be timestamps, all othes are floats.

Comment: `$ident_same_update`  i use it a primary key like id in the items , the result of the array is 8 is the same number of requet number

Comment: `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ident = '352625694095173'' `

Comment: Your SQL statement contains a comma before the `WHERE`. This could be the cause of the syntax error.

Comment: thank you so much carsten , haha i got new error:(  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'server.timestamp' in 'field list' in`